# When do you use definite articles?

Tags: articles, nouns

When do you use certain definite articles in the Italian language?

I’m learning on Duolingo and it seems to be random wether a noun has a definite article or not.

I know it’s different to English in the sense that more words are preceded by definite articles, but is there a rule to which ones are and does it rely on the situation?

One example is “La donna mangia panini” (The woman eats sandwiches) but then “La donna mangia **le** mele” (The woman eats apples) requires a definite article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first approximation, saying *la donna mangia panini*, while being a legitimate way to say “the woman eats sandwiches”, sounds slightly wooden, like that's the only thing she eats, a bit like saying that a herbivore feeds on such and such. *La donna mangia i panini* would mostly mean that she is eating some particular sandwiches we already know about. Finally, *la donna mangia dei panini* is a possible way to say that she eats (some, generic) sandwiches. Of course, the same holds for *la donna mangia -/le/delle mele*.

A general coverage of the use in Italian of definite articles (*i panini*), indefinite articles (*un panino*), partitive articles (*dei panini*) or no article at all (*panini*) would require a book, including situations that, while not at all random, are nevertheless very idiomatic. For instance you often use definite article even with a generic noun, rather than one you have recently mentioned (for instance, I love coffee = *Mi piace il caffè*).

<sub>Sorry to say so, but just with Duolingo you'll never get even close to catching these nuances, said as one who's giving Duolingo a chance but is exasperated by its utter lack of explanations.</sub>

Comment: What other apps/websites would you suggest to learn with?

Comment: @Th3Ark1t3kt Duolingo is fine, but it needs to be treated as an exercise book and not enough to learn the language on its own. When learning German I supplemented it with a grammar book, and it worked more or less fine (I also used the Assimil courses at the same time, so I cannot credit only that for my learning outcomes)

Comment: @DenisNardin: This way, Duolingo is kind of a stone soup...  :D

Comment: @DaG No, I don't want to repeat myself, but Duolingo's approach is great for forcing you to do some small exercise every day - which is very valuable in my opinion, especially if you're trying to learn a language in your spare time. As I said, it's a valid exercise book, which is an important component of the language learning process. I would love if it had better explanations and more complex listening exercises, but hey, it's free so why complain :)

Comment: Yes, I see your point, and indeed I'm presently using it as you say, but often I feel it's not the best way to use my time, even as a portable exercise book. Mostly random exercises, with no context, perhaps repeating stuff I know, and with no connection to the subjects I'm interested in. I'm about to abandon it, and force myself to read or listen a bit every day. (I know: we are going heavily off topic. Sorry!)

Comment: @Th3Ark1t3kt: I'm sorry, I'm not an expert in teaching techniques. Personally, I'm kind of old-fashioned: when studying a language, I follow a grammar or a structured course in book form, I frequently browse a dictionary and possibly an etymological one too, and read stuff I'm interested in (from news to short stories or essays in topics I know something about, to have some basis). I watch some film and tv series, but I should do this more.